# What expressions other than ${user.home} can I use in my Tomcat context.xml file?

Tags: java, sqlite, tomcat

I'm using Tomcat 8.0 and in my $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml file, I can use expressions such as ${user.home} to specify where a file is located. For example, the following configuration is valid and will look in the home directory of the user that Tomcat is running under for the .keystore file:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Now I'm trying to configure a DataSource to a sqlite database in my web applications META-INF/context.xml file like this:

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/database"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            driverClassName="org.sqlite.JDBC"
            url="jdbc:sqlite:/absolute/path/to/my/db/database.db">
```

I've read that the value specified in the "url" attribute is relative to the $CATALINA_HOME directory. So I can only specify paths that are sub-directories of $CATALINA_HOME. Because my database is not located under the $CATALINA_HOME directory, I am looking for a way to set the url either dynamically or using a path relative to my web application.

For example, if my web application has the following layout:

/absolute/path/to/my/web/application/

/absolute/path/to/my/web/application/WEB-INF

/absolute/path/to/my/web/application/WEB-INF/db/database.db

How do I get Tomcat to locate my database using either a relative path or have the path specified externally?

Is there a list of expressions similar to ${user.home} that I can pick from that might work? What other variables are available to Tomcat other than ${user.home}? Can I read in any environment variable from the context.xml file? For example, if I had an environment variable named "db_path", could I use ${user.db_path}?

Comment: Check out: http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/user-home-and-other-server-xml-tags-accepted-by-Tomcat-td2117599.html

Comment: If you can use `user.home` I would expect you can use the same syntax for any system property at all.